# Url change in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, url-rewriting

Hi Iam new to zend framework. When i try to get a page by example.com/index.php/contact contact is action in index controller. Not only that when trying get module using example.com/index.php/admin. Can any one help how to remove that index.php from url

Answer (score 0):

[Rewrite Configuration Guide](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/project-structure.rewrite.html)

Hope that helps.

Comment: @user2165091 if that helped & now works please accept Boulevard's answer by clicking on the green tick on the left of their answer